# R, nested condition for filling cells

Tags: r

I couldn't find any solution anywhere.

This is my data frame:

```
A    B   
5.6  0
2.4  3
5.7  2 
8.1  1
6.3  0
3.5  3
2.5  2
1.3  1
7.8  0
```

I need to arrange it like this:

```
A    B   C    D     
5.6  0
2.4  3   5.7  8.1 
5.7  2 
8.1  1
6.3  0
3.5  3   2.5  1.3
2.5  2
1.3  1
7.8  0
```

I want to create a column C, D and E.
If B=3, then C should have the value in column A of the next row.
If B=3, then D should have the value in column A of the second next row.

I tried it with lag variables of the kind 
`df$lag3 = c(rep(NA, 3), df$dist[1:(length(df$dist)-3)])`
but I failed

Answer (score 0):

Note - the solution depends on the order of your rows (without any type of indexing variable), so care should be taken with this type of manipulation.

#### Solution:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(C = ifelse(B == 3, lead(A, order_by = row_number()), NA),
         D = ifelse(B == 3, lead(A, n = 2, order_by = row_number()), NA))

    A B   C   D
1 5.6 0  NA  NA
2 2.4 3 5.7 8.1
3 5.7 2  NA  NA
4 8.1 1  NA  NA
5 6.3 0  NA  NA
6 3.5 3 2.5 1.3
7 2.5 2  NA  NA
8 1.3 1  NA  NA
9 7.8 0  NA  NA
```

#### Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(5.6, 2.4, 5.7, 8.1, 6.3, 3.5, 2.5, 1.3, 
                            7.8), B = c(0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("A", 
                                                                                         "B"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.frame"
                                                                                         ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option without using a library

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(df1$A), function(x) c(df1[x,], if(df1$B[x] == 3) c(df1$A[x + 1], df1$A[x + 2]) else c(NA, NA)))))

colnames(df1)[c(3, 4)] <- c("C", "D")

> df1
    A B   C   D
1 5.6 0  NA  NA
2 2.4 3 5.7 8.1
3 5.7 2  NA  NA
4 8.1 1  NA  NA
5 6.3 0  NA  NA
6 3.5 3 2.5 1.3
7 2.5 2  NA  NA
8 1.3 1  NA  NA
9 7.8 0  NA  NA
```